# Tried to add a trigger 'On form Submit' and worked as intended for me

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a Google form that feeds a spreadsheet with responses.

The sheet has a script with an installable trigger that is supposed to run on every form submission:

!g

Comment: Tried to add a trigger 'On form Submit' and worked as intended for me.

Comment: Yes, and in another form I have the trigger is running well. I changed the trigger to "once a minute" and it also works fine.

Answer (score 16):

I've had the same problem with scripts attached to spreadsheets not triggering on form submission.  Try deleting the trigger, creating a new version of the script (`File` menu > `Manage versions...`) & then recreating the trigger.

Comment: Just did a delete and recreate – *identical* trigger – and had my script successfully run. Disconcerting, but glad it's working.

Comment: 2 years later. same issue. same solution

Comment: Hi, I had something similar but not exactly. Script sometimes works sometimes not...